# Could not AOT the assembly in Native binding Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, aot

I have been trying to convert this native (Objective-C) project to Xamarin.iOS for so long but have not been able to make it work.

I have followed all the tutorials available online to bind to the native library.

I have .a files (given in the sample) as suggested in many of the tutorials I converted it to .dll through Xamarin.iOS Binding Library project and Objective Sharpie to generate API definition classes. However, I get numerous errors which I somehow resolved and generated a .dll file. However it doesn't work in the Xamarin project and gives the following error: "Could not AOT the assembly ...SP530.dll".

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could push me in the right direction, I have been working on it for so long.

It's a credit card swiper integration and this is the sample Xcode project I'm trying to bind:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/knokrg38y7kc6d2/SP530_iOS_SDK_v2.0.0.rar

Here is the log that was generated during the biuld:

```
Target '/Users/shaikhawais/Projects/BindingTestSP530/BindingTestSP530/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad4.5-10.3.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/libmscorlib.dll.dylib' does not exist.
        Target(s) /Users/shaikhawais/Projects/BindingTestSP530/BindingTestSP530/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad4.5-10.3.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/libmscorlib.dll.dylib must be rebuilt.
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -framework Security -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -weak_framework CoreFoundation -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path /Users/shaikhawais/Projects/BindingTestSP530/BindingTestSP530/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad4.5-10.3.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/mscorlib.dll.o /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libxamarin-debug.dylib -lz -gdwarf-2 -std=c99 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk -Qunused-arguments -miphoneos-version-min=10.3 -arch arm64 -shared -read_only_relocs suppress -install_name @rpath/libmscorlib.dll.dylib -fapplication-extension -o /Users/shaikhawais/Projects/BindingTestSP530/BindingTestSP530/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad4.5-10.3.1/mtouch-cache/arm64/libmscorlib.dll.dylib -DDEBUG
        MTOUCH : error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/shaikhawais/Projects/BindingTestSP530/BindingTestSP530/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad4.5-10.3.1/mtouch-cache/Build/LibraryTestSP530.dll'
          at Xamarin.Bundler.AOTTask+<ExecuteAsync>c__async1.MoveNext () [0x001dc] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/BuildTasks.mtouch.cs:256 
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask+<Execute>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0024c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:247 
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask+<Execute>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002eb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:258 
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask+<Execute>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002eb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:258 
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask+<Execute>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000c7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:229 
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask+<Execute>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002eb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:258 
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask+<Execute>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002eb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:258 
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTask+<Execute>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002eb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:258 
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
          at Xamarin.Bundler.BuildTasks+<ExecuteBuildTasks>c__AnonStorey5+<ExecuteBuildTasks>c__async4.MoveNext () [0x00034] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/tools/common/BuildTasks.cs:49 
        The command exited with code 1.
        Output Property: _CompiledArchitectures=ARM64
      Done executing task "MTouch" -- FAILED.
    Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "BindingTestSP530.csproj" -- FAILED.
```